# Is the rule of mixtures applicable for calculating the permeation of a mixture of gases?

Tags: chemistry, packaging-engineering

Say we have 2 gases with permeation coefficients $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ when permeating a specific solid.

If the permeating substance is now a mixture of the 2, can we say that the total permeation is
$$P=f_{1}P_{1}+f_{2}P_{2}$$
with $f_{i}$ some weighting factor, like the volume fraction or the mass fraction of the respective substance.

If not, can we apply the inequality of the linear rom as upper bound and the inverse rom as lower bound?

**If so, could you please give a reference paper/pdf?**

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "rom"?

Comment: rom= Rule Of Mixtures